# How can I start finding max,min by starting from None?

Tags: python

The code below is to find the largest and smallest numbers for the sequential input of `[7, 2, bob, 10, 4]` and after the inputs, I type 'done' and the loop is done and prints the **max, min** numbers. I checked whether this code actually works but what really bothers me is that the basic setting of this quiz started for the largest and smallest from **None**. But if I start the variables from none, somehow it returns invalid input, I guess there are problems somewhere in the try box.
How can I modify this code to use **None** at first?

```
largest = 0
smallest = 9999
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    try:
        fnum=float(num)
        if fnum>largest :
            largest=fnum
            continue
        if fnum<smallest :
            smallest=fnum
            continue
    except :
        if num == "done" : break
        else :
            print('invalid input')
            continue
print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```

Comment: Take a look at the dupe, which tells you about finding max in a mixed list, and extend that logic to find min

Comment: @Devesh ... the question here explicitly states that OP wants to start with `largest = smallest = None`. The dupe is a bit far-reaching, I disagree with it...

Comment: Sure, I  have added another dupe which finds max and min via iteration, that should help the OP too

Comment: `quiz started for the largest and smallest from None` does that mean `largest=smallest=None` needs to be defined @myfan?